# Display in Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have to display all Full name values in TABLEVIEW from the following json. How can i do that? Below is how my json data looks a like. Should i need to convert all to Array or can i use Dictionary?

```
"Beneficiaries": [

    {

        "BeneficiaryType": "Individual",
        "CustomerID": 512,
        "ID": 258,
        "Title": "Mr",
        "Firstname": "zympay",
        "Surname": "test1",
        "Fullname": "zympay test1",
        "Address1": "East Central",
        "Address2": "EC",
        "City": "EC",
        "State": "Londan",
        "Country": "ZW",
        "Telephone": "26322334455",
        "Mobile": "4443523452345",
        "Email": "zympaytest1@mailinator.com",
        "isDefault": true,
        "DateOfBirth": "/Date(510969600000-0000)/",
        "PreferredService": "Cash Payment",
        "Account": {},
        "Bills": [
            {
                "ID": 38,
                "ProviderID": 4,
                "ProviderName": "Test Provider",
                "PaymentReference": "Test Provider"
            },
            {
                "ID": 39,
                "ProviderID": 4,
                "ProviderName": "Test Provider",
                "PaymentReference": "Test Provider"
            }
        ]
    },
    {

        "BeneficiaryType": "Individual",
        "CustomerID": 512,
        "ID": 283,
        "Title": "Mr",
        "Firstname": "kandan",
        "Surname": "Mani",
        "Fullname": "kandan Mani",
        "Address1": "19 Street",
        "Address2": "Chennai",
        "City": "Chennai",
        "Zipcode": "",
        "State": "TN",
        "Country": "ZW",
        "Mobile": "2632345234523",
        "Email": "mani@gmail.com",
        "CardNumber": "",
        "isDefault": false,
        "DateOfBirth": "/Date(157185960000-0000)/",
        "PreferredService": "Cash Payment",
        "Account": {
            "AccountNumber": "",
            "AccountName": "",
            "BankAddress": "",
            "IBAN": "",
            "SWIFT": "",
            "BankName": "",
            "BankCity": ""
        },
```

I used the following code to convert the json to Dictionary.

```
NSData *GetBeneficiaries = [newStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *parsejson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:GetBeneficiaries options:0 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array to store "Beneficiaries". Let's follow below instruction:-

```
NSMutableArray * beneficiariesArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[parsejson  objectForKey:@"Beneficiaries"]];
```

Then

```
  -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

  cell.textLabel.text = [[beneficiariesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fullname"];


#pragma -Mark UITableView Delegate methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return beneficiariesArr.count;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString * CellID = @"CellID";

      UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID];

        if (!cell)
        {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellID];

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

       cell.textLabel.text = [[beneficiariesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fullname"];

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: Why a *mutable* array?  Why not just `NSArray *beneficiaries = parsejson objectForKey:@"Beneficiaries"];`?  You also seem to have a major scoping issue (`beneficiariesArr` is a local variable and it needs to be an instance variable).

Comment: Yes, We can use NSArray as well. But NSMutableArray will be used to modify the values, if user wants.

Comment: Sure. You have to implement the tableview delegate and datasource methods for a UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

You could leave it as it is, however it's better to convert it to an array of custom objects which will allow you to do more with the data elsewhere in your app.

For example you can provide methods to serialize the data to a database, over the network, or to perform more complex calculations on the dataset.

This becomes much easier when the data is in a custom object rather than a generic dictionary using strings to represent everything (not to mention efficiency).